# Android Picker with String

Tags: android, time, picker

I have got a simple idea.

I would like to use a picker like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqliP.png)
and insert Strings into it. 
Has anyone an idea how to realize that ?

So instead of the numbers I would like to insert names into the 
round time picker.

Here is a sample [implementation](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) for the usual time picker.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out from the [source code](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/wdullaer/materialdatetimepicker/time/RadialTextsView.java), basically these numbers inside the Circular are just **Texts over the Bitmaps**.

The basic principle to achieve that goal is to use Canvas class. Canvas holds the "draw" calls. So to draw something, you need 4 basic components:

- A Bitmap to hold the pixels
- a Canvas to host the draw calls (writing into the bitmap)
- a drawing primitive (e.g. Rect, Path, text, Bitmap) and
- a paint (to describe the colors and styles for the drawing).

So we create Paint object and set them text size, color, shadow, etc using Canvas object.

A typical example for using Canvas:

```
 Paint paint = new Paint(); 
 paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
 paint.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
 canvas.drawPaint(paint); 

 paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
 paint.setTextSize(20); 
 canvas.drawText("Text to be drawn", x-co ord, y-co ord, paint obj);
```

---

**But**, since the input type parameter for Text setup for initializing the [drawTexts()](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/wdullaer/materialdatetimepicker/time/RadialTextsView.java) is already in String format in the link you mentioned, thing that is required to change as you can see [here](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/wdullaer/materialdatetimepicker/time/RadialPickerLayout.java)  in the `initialize()` method is to change the 3 int arrays defined namely `hours`, `hours_24` and `minutes` to String arrays that you want.

This will make the Texts display "One", "Two", "Three" etc. rather than "1", "2", "3".

Ofcourse, you will have to change the type of other getter/setters or any other methods that calls this initialize() and that relates to these int arrays **everywhere**.

I hope it helps.